# How to make this partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

$$p\left(p+\frac{i}{m}\right)=P_o\left(P_o+\frac{i}{m})(1-\frac{x}{L}\right)$$

For brevity of notation, let $$g \equiv \left(1-\frac{x}{L}\right)$$

and $$a \equiv \frac{i}{m}$$

Taking the partial derivative of the equation with respect to time yields:

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=\frac{g \sqrt{c+1}}{\sqrt{c+g}} \cdot P'_o(t)$$

where

$$c=\frac{a^2}{4P_0(P_0+a)}$$

and $$P'_0(t)=\frac{\mathrm dP_0}{\mathrm dt}.$$

What are the steps for this differentiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p^2+a\,p-g\,P_0(P_0+a)=(p-p_1)(p-p_2)=p^2-(p_1+p_2)p+p_1p_2$$
It follows that
$$p_1+p_2=-a$$
$$p_1p_2=-gP_0(P_0+a)$$
Solving these equations yields
$$p_{1,2}=\frac 12\Big(\pm\sqrt{a^2+4agP_0+4gP_0^2}-a\Big)$$
Assuming that $P_0(t)$ and using $p=p_1$
$$dp=\frac 14\frac{4ag\,P_0'+8gP_0P_0'}{\sqrt{a^2+4gP_0(P_0+a)}}dt$$
$$\frac{dp}{dt}=g\frac{a+2P_0}{\sqrt{a^2+4gP_0(P_0+a)}}P_0'$$
$$\frac{dp}{dt}=g\frac{\sqrt{(a+2P_0)^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+4gP_0(P_0+a)}}P_0'$$
$$\frac{dp}{dt}=g\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4aP_0+4P_0^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+4gP_0(P_0+a)}}P_0'$$
$$\frac{dp}{dt}=g\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4P_0(P_0+a)}}{\sqrt{a^2+4gP_0(P_0+a)}}P_0'$$
$$\frac{dp}{dt}=g\frac{\sqrt{a^2/\big(4P_0(P_0+a)\big)+1}}{\sqrt{a^2/\big(4P_0(P_0+a)\big)+g}}P_0'$$
$$\frac{dp}{dt}=g\frac{\sqrt{c+1}}{\sqrt{c+g}}P_0'$$

Comment: First I want to say thank you very much for taking the time to help me with my problem. When solving for the intercepts of the quadratic polynomial $P_{1,2}$ I get $\pm \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}+gP_o(P_o+a)}-\frac{a}{2}$ , factoring the 4 from the denominator left me with $\frac{1}{4} \Big(\pm \sqrt{a^2+4agP_o+4gP_o^2}-2a \Big)$. Am I off somewhere? And could you explain how and what it is you are doing in the next step from there?

Comment: Specifically, I would appreciate an explanation and the steps on how you went from this: $p_{1,2}=\frac 12\Big(\pm\sqrt{a^2+4agP_0+4gP_0^2}-a\Big)$ to this $dp=\frac 14\frac{4ag\,P_0'+8gP_0P_0'}{\sqrt{a^2+4gP_0(P_0+a)}}dt$ ?

Comment: For $p_{1,2}$ use the regular rule; such as $x^2+ax+b=0$ has the roots $x_{1,2}=\pm \frac 12 \bigg(\sqrt{a^2-4b}-a\bigg)$. Check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Derivation_of_the_quadratic_formula For the rest of the derivation are you familiar with chain rule?

Comment: Ah, you know what, I used wolfram alpha and I now see how that derivative was performed. I tend to jump the gun with my questions sometimes before I investigate enough.  I am familiar with the chain rule but that is it, I'm just aware of it.  Recognizing and applying the chain rule is something I haven't practiced enough of.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jakemcgregor You welcome